# JAVA YAML read/write subset of variables in data structure

Tags: java, yaml, snakeyaml

I am writing a JAVA program that backs up the data in a data structure to a YAML file.  However, this data structure omits protected data for read/write access from the user.  Is there a way to setup custom data types or flag the Jackson yaml library to only read/write certain variables in a data structure?

Below is some test code I have been working on.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect.Visibility;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.PropertyAccessor;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLFactory;
package swt;

public class swm{   
   
    static class dataStructInner{
        int  accessible;
        int forbidden;   //ignore reads/writes to this variable in YAML i/o
        public dataStructInner(int accessible, int forbidden) {
            this.accessible = accessible;
            this.forbidden = forbidden;
        }
        public dataStructInner(int accessible) {
            this.accessible = accessible;
            this.forbidden = this.forbidden;
        }
        public dataStructInner() {
            this.accessible = 0;
            this.forbidden = this.forbidden;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "dataStructInner{" + "accessible=" + accessible + ", forbidden=" + forbidden + '}';
        }
        
    }
    static class dataArray{          //
        int  accessible;
        private int  forbidden;     //ignore reads/writes to this variable in YAML i/o
        dataStructInner nested;

        public dataArray(int accessible, int forbidden, dataStructInner E) {
            this.accessible = accessible;
            this.forbidden = forbidden;
            this.nested = E;
        }
        public dataArray(int accessible, dataStructInner E) {
            this.accessible = accessible;
            this.forbidden = this.forbidden;
            this.nested = E;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "dataArray{" + "accessible=" + accessible + ", forbidden=" + forbidden + ", nested=" + nested.toString() + '}';
        }
        public dataArray() {
            this.accessible = 0;
            this.forbidden = this.forbidden;
        }
        
    }
    static class JSONExample{
        String header;
        dataArray[] data;
        String footer;
        public JSONExample(String header, dataArray[] data, String closing) {
            this.header = header;
            this.data = data;
            this.footer = closing;
        }
        public JSONExample() {
            this.header = "default header";
            this.data = null;
            this.footer = "default footer";
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            String getArraydata = data[0].toString() + data[1].toString();
            return "JSONExample{" + "header=" + header + "\n, data=" + getArraydata + "\nfooter=" + footer + '}';
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, Exception{
        ObjectMapper om;
        om = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
        om.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);
        
        File txYamlWrite = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "YAMLWriteTest");
        File txYamlRead = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "YAMLReadTest");
        File txYamlWriteFinal = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "YAMLWriteTestFinal");

        dataStructInner inner0, inner1;
        inner0 = new dataStructInner(0x00, 0xCD);
        inner1 = new dataStructInner(0x01, 0xFF);
        dataArray [] data;
        data = new dataArray[2];
        data[0] = new dataArray(0x00, 0xAB, inner0);
        data[1] = new dataArray(0x01, 0xEF, inner1);
        JSONExample exampleObj;
        exampleObj = new JSONExample("header", data, "footer");
        
//write populated data to YAML formatted file
        String yamlString = null;
        try {
            yamlString = om.writeValueAsString(exampleObj);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(yamlString);
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(txYamlWrite);
        writer.write(yamlString);
        writer.close();
        
//read in new data from a YAML file which omits the unwanted data members
//This naturally generates an InvalidDefinitionException as some data was omitted.
        try {
            exampleObj = om.readValue(txYamlRead, JSONExample.class);
            yamlString = om.writeValueAsString(exampleObj);
        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
//write changes out to verify
        writer = new FileWriter(txYamlWriteFinal);
        writer.write(yamlString);
        writer.close();
//echo result
        System.out.println(exampleObj.toString());
      
    }
```

This is the content of YAMLWriteTest

```
header: "header"
data:
- accessible: 0
  forbidden: 171
  nested:
    accessible: 0
    forbidden: 205
- accessible: 1
  forbidden: 239
  nested:
    accessible: 1
    forbidden: 255
footer: "footer"
```

This is the input for YAMLReadTest

```
header: "new header"
data:
- accessible: 10
  nested:
    accessible: 20
- accessible: 30
  nested:
    accessible: 40
footer: "new footer"
```

Running this code generates the exception: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `swt.swm$JSONExample` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator).

This is expected behavior since the yaml does not contain all of the variables in the inner classes.

To summarize, is it possible for yaml to handle "deserialized"/missing data, or will it be necessary to program a subclass that contains my YAML public data, which calls setters and getters in my main data structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use the constructor when deserializing, you need to annotate the parameters with `@JsonProperty` in order to name the parameters for the deserializer.

```java
public dataStructInner(@JsonProperty("accessible") int accessible,
                       @JsonProperty("forbidden") int forbidden) {
```

```java
public dataArray(@JsonProperty("accessible") int accessible,
                 @JsonProperty("forbidden") int forbidden,
                 @JsonProperty("nested") dataStructInner E) {
```

```java
public JSONExample(@JsonProperty("header") String header,
                   @JsonProperty("data") dataArray[] data,
                   @JsonProperty("footer") String closing) {
```

If you don't want the serialization to write out the `forbidden` properties, you can annotate the field with `@JsonIgnore`.

```java
@JsonIgnore
int  forbidden;   //ignore reads/writes to this variable in YAML i/o
```

Missing values are deserialized with their default value, i.e. `0` for `int` properties.

Comment: Thank you, I've changed the test code by adding multiple constructors.  This lets the code run without generating the exception, but as you said, it is overwriting my forbidden data to the default value.  I will test with these new annotations.